# In Kotlin can I create a range that counts backwards?

Tags: range, kotlin

I looked at [the documentation for the Ranges](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/Kotlin/Ranges) and I see no mention of backwards ranges.

Is it possible to do something like:

```
for (n in 100..1) {
    println(n)
}
```

And get results:

```
100
99
98
...
```

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Use `downTo` as in:

```
for (n in 100 downTo 1) {
//
}
```

Comment: Why it's not "for (n in 100..1)"? Couldn't it be an agreement that if the first number is bigger then a range counts backwards?

Comment: Is there something that excludes the lower limit ? e.g. if I want from 100 till 2. and want to exclude 1.

Comment: @x2bool, though it is useful, there are situations, where it is not. For instance, you want to loop from `0` to `count - 1`, but don't want to check limits (like in Java). If `count` becomes 0, you will have `0 downto -1` which will break an algorythm.

Comment: @MobileAppDeveloper, if limits are integer, you can add `1` to lower limit.

Comment: what's the difference among `down to 1`, `down to 2`, `down to 30`?

Comment: Use `for (n in 100 downTo 1 step 2)` to skip one index.

Answer (score 27):

As pointed by others, the correct answer is

```
for (n in 100 downTo 1) {
    println(n)
}
```

But why did Kotlin team chose `100 downTo 1` vs `100..1`?

I think that the syntax `100..1` would be bad when we try to use variables instead of literals.
If we typed

`for (n in b..a)`

then it wouldn't be clear what loop we wanted to use.

We may have intended to count backwards but if `b` turns out to be smaller than `a`, then our program would actually count upwards! That would be a source of bugs.

Answer (score 27):

Just as an example of an universal range function for "for":

```
private infix fun Int.toward(to: Int): IntProgression {
    val step = if (this > to) -1 else 1
    return IntProgression.fromClosedRange(this, to, step)
}
```

Usage:

```
// 0 to 100
for (i in 0 toward 100) {
    // Do things
}

// 100 downTo 0
for (i in 100 toward 0) {
    // Do things
}
```

Comment: So there is no native Kotlin equivalent to this?

Comment: I haven't found one. You can get the same result, for example using [step](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.ranges/step.html) function for some Progression, but still need to calculate the step by yourself. I suppose, Kotlin architects want to create a perfectly readable language. That means code execution have to be exactly the same as written, and universal infix function like my "toward" doesn't completely fit to that idea.

Answer (score 14):

Reversed ranges are supported using the minus `-` unary operator as in `-(1..100)`.

To invoke a method on that range, you will then need to surround it with parentheses as in

```
(-(1..100)).foreach { println(it) }
```

Comment: Is there any possibility of making the rangeTo() function a bit smarter and handling that automatically? Having a negative range to me means counting from -1 to -100.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at the following issues related to ranges in Kotlin and submit a new issue explaining in detail your suggestion:
[KT-861](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-861), [KT-1045](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1045), [KT-1076](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-1076)

Comment: This doesn't pass static analysis in kotlin 1.3

Answer (score 6):

```
(100 downto 1).map{ println(it) }
```

Comment: There is no reason to use `map()` if we don't want to create a list filled by `Unit`s.

Comment: @PavloZhukov, yes, we can use `forEach` instead.